# name list option list keep multiply

Tags: jquery

```
function addteamSection() {
    var teamList = $('#team_table');
    var team_temp = '';
    var size_temp = ["20", "30", "40", "50", "60"];

    teamList.append("<tr><td><input class='name' type='text' name='player_name' /></td><td><input class='number' type='text' name='player_number' /></td><td><select class='sizeList'></select></td></tr>");

    for (var s = 0; s < size_temp.length; s++) {
        var sizeList = $('.sizeList');
        team_temp += "<option value=" + size_temp[s] + ">" + size_temp[s] + "</option>";
    }

    sizeList.append(team_temp);

}
```

my intention is make a add name list by click the button , and it will have age selection for user to choice on , but my option keep multiply because i have the same class name , but how i supposen to add to select not using any id and make sure it was no multiply.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/xu4ptzvd/5/)

keep click a few time add and check the first option , it repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Separate out your string building like this.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/xu4ptzvd/8/).

```
function addteamSection(){
        var teamList = $('#team_table');
        var team_temp = '';
        var size_temp = ["20", "30", "40", "50","60"];

        var rowString = "<tr><td><input class='name' type='text' name='player_name' /></td><td><input class='number' type='text' name='player_number' /></td><td>"
        var selectString = "<select class='sizeList'>"

        /* Instead of using var sizeList = $('.sizeList'); to select the new dropdown
           (which won't work anyway because your new element hasn't been added to the 
           DOM yet.) You can manually build the select box, append the options to it
           and then append it to your DOM element.*/

        for(var s = 0; s < size_temp.length; s++){

            selectString += "<option value="+size_temp[s]+">"+size_temp[s]+"</option>";
        }

    selectString+="</select></td></tr>";
    rowString+=selectString;
    teamList.append(rowString);


    }
addteamSection();

$('#addf').click(function() {
    addteamSection();
});
```

Comment: AdityaParab you there ?

Comment: could you help me check again , i tried to add loop number inside , and i try to break like you did. why is not working ? i want add 1. 2. 3 ....